# Year based primary key

Tags: sql-server, database-design

How can I create a primary key in SQL Server 2005/2008 of the format `CurrentYear + auto-increment`? If current year is 2010, in a new table ID should start at 1, so: 20101, 20102, 20103, 20104, 20105 and so on.

Comment: Can't you simply set the identity seed starting value to 20100?

Comment: @Kane But this way after 20109, it will sum to 20110!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This technically meets the needs of what you requested:

```
CREATE TABLE #test
        ( seeded_column INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        , year_column INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(YEAR(GETDATE()))
        , calculated_column AS CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(CHAR(4), year_column, 120) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), seeded_column)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY
        , test VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #test (test)
SELECT 'Badda'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Cadda'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dadda'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fadda'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gadda'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hadda'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jadda'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Kadda'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ladda'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Madda'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Nadda'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Padda';

SELECT *
FROM #test;

DROP TABLE #test;
```

Comment: After rereading @Pontus Gagge I see that this is exactly what he recommended.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Note this will not work if you want the first record of 2011 to start over again at 1.

Answer (score 9):

The [cleaner solution](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx) is to create a [composite primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) consisting of e.g. `Year` and `Counter` columns.

Comment: My assumption is that the keys are going to be visible to end users (such as a order numbering scheme). Otherwise, I'd recommend a purely synthetic key.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish by doing that, but it makes a lot more sense to do this with two fields.

If the combination of the two must be the PK for some reason, just span it across both columns. However, it seems unnecessary since the identity part will be unique exclusive of the year.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a trigger for this :)

Have a separate table for storing the last digit used (I really don't know whether there is something similar to sequences in Oracle in SQL Server).

OR

You can get the last item inserted item and extract the last number of it.

THEN

You can get the current year from `SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,GetDate());`

The trigger would be a `ON INSERT` trigger where you combine the year and the last digit and update the column

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it for display purposes you can also consider using a subquery:

```
SELECT Id,
(SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(YEAR(SubMyTable.DateCreated), '_', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SubMyTable.DateCreated))
FROM MyTable as SubMyTable
WHERE YEAR(SubMyTable.DateCreated) = YEAR(MyTable.DateCreated) AND SubMyTable.DateCreated <= MyTable.DateCreated
ORDER BY SubMyTable.DateCreated DESC) as Number
FROM MyTable
```

A downside of this approach is, when a record is deleted, this will change all the numbers after this record.

To prevent this, a trigger can be used:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerGenerateNumberPerYear
   ON  dbo.Table 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Table 
    WITH (TABLOCK)
    SET Number = CONCAT(
        YEAR(Table.DateCreated), 
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table as CountTable WHERE YEAR(CountTable.DateCreated) = YEAR(Table.DateCreated)) + 1 - (SELECT TOP 1 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY inserted.Id) FROM inserted WHERE inserted.Id <= Table.Id ORDER BY inserted.Id DESC)
    )
    FROM Table
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM inserted)
END
GO
```

This will lock the table an prevent concurrency issues. Also the value will be stored on a table column.

More alternative approaches are described here: https://ben-5.azurewebsites.net/2023/10/09/consecutive-number-per-year-with-entity-framework-core/